# Finding the parameter values of parametrized curve

Tags: parametrization

I'm kinda confused on how to find the values that a parameter takes given two points of parametrized curve, this is the problem I have:

> Parametrize $y=x^2$ in the interval of the two points $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ find the values of the parameter where this function takes value.

My solution was this, the parametrizatition is $x=t$ and $y=t^2$, this results in the fuction $\alpha =t \hat i+t^2 \hat j$, but I don't know what are the values of $t$ in the interval $(-1,1)\cup(1,1)$ for the parametrized curve.

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you are very confused or if you are just using poor notation.  You talk about $(-1, 1)\cup (1, 1)$ as if (-1, 1) and (1, 1) were intervals but you had already said that (-1, 1) and (1, 1) are **points**, not intervals!  You have x= t so the values for t are just the values for x, -1 to 1.

Comment: Just realized that myself, feel stupid myself now. Thanks though.

Comment: Always happy to make people feel stupid!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose an arbitrarily small step say 0.1

$$ x= \pm(.1,.2..3,.4,.5,.. 0.8,0.9,1)$$
$$ y= +(.01,.04,.09,.16,.25, ... 0.64,0.81, 1.0) $$

Comment: That way I could get the interval where $t$ takes values, but couldn't be a methed to achieve this more rapidly?

Comment: Or could I just evaluate $\alpha =t \hat i+t^2 \hat j$ in the two points I'm given to find the interval where $t$ takes values?

Comment: You are given endpoints. You can parametrize with regard to $x$ or slope or arc length. Step interval is to be chosen based on a choice of one of these for example..that is all your choice.